# action of $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ on ${S}^{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, matrices, lie-groups, group-actions

Is the action of $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ on ${S}^{n-1}$ transitive? I think this is true as orthogonal matrices are supposed to rotate and keep the length fixed, but how do I prove this?

**EDIT:** Based on Alexander's comment, if $x = (x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}) \in S^{n-1}$, then I can construct a matrix $A$ whose first row is the vector $x$ and whose other rows can be obtained by completing it to an orthonormal basis. But does it ensure that columns are also orthogonal?

Comment: Given a point $x \in S^{n-1}$, maybe try constructing a matrix that takes $x$ to some point $(1, 0,...,0)$. If you can show this for any such $x$, this proves transitivity.

Comment: Answer to your edit question: That the columns of a matrix $A$ are orthogonal, is precisely the condition $AA^T=I$. Transposing both sides, we get $(AA^T)^T=AA^T=I$, so the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @FredrickMeyer I think you mean that columns are orthogonal precisely means that $A^{T}A = I$ and rows are orthogonal means $AA^{T} = I$. So transposing the condition for rows gives the condition for columns.

Comment: @Alexander How do we show that there is a matrix that takes $x$ to $(1,0,...,0)$? 

The answer below shows how to obtain a matrix in $O(n)$ that takes $(1,0,...,0)$ to $x \in S^{n-1}$, for any $x$.

Comment: @Alexander Ok I think I got the answer to my question. Since $A(1,0,...,0)^t = x^t$, we have $A^tA(1,0,...,0)^t = (1,0,...,0)^t = A^t x^t$, and as $A^t \in O(n)$, we are done.

Comment: @Saikat Sounds good!

Answer (score 2):

A [very closely related recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/453659/11619), where it is shown that you can rotate any point to the South Pole. As you are not picky about the sign of the determinant let me summarize: Let $A$ and $B$ be two distinct points on the sphere. What happens if you reflect the sphere w.r.t. the (hyper)plane $H$ that has $\vec{AB}$ as its normal and bisects the line segment $AB$?

If $\vec{n}=\vec{AB}$, then the formula for the said reflection is
$$
\vec{x}\mapsto \vec{x}-2\frac{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{n}}{\Vert\vec{n}\Vert^2}\,\vec{n}.
$$
With $\vec{n}$ known finding the matrix of this reflection is straightforward.

Comment: A reflection preserves lengths of vectors, thus also angles between them, and thus belongs to $O(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1):

With the said alexander:Let $x$ be a arbitary point in $S^{n-1}$,we know there exist a orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{R^n},\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n$ and $\alpha_1=x$,now consider the linear map $T:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R^n}$ s,t $e_i\mapsto\alpha_i(e_i$is standard basis which is also orthonormal).

Call the matrix of $T$,$A$.$A$ is orthonormal and$A{(1,0,...,0)}^t=x^t$.[here PROPOSITION 10C part(b)](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnlafolder/la10.pdf)

Comment: Do we also need to ensure that any $x \in S^n$ can also be mapped to $(1,0,...,0)$ via some orthogonal matrix?